# Azure Pipeline Blob Prefix

Tags: azure, blob, devops

I have Job running in Azure Dev Ops pipeline , and the basically I'm uploading the Artifacts to Azure Blob Storage .

[image]

But I would like to do that each new Commit (Each new pipeline run) new folder will be created in azure with different name : For example

Version1 , Version2 , Version3.

How can i do it ? maybe i need to write something in BlobPrefix ?

Answer (score 0):

> How can i do it ? maybe i need to write something in BlobPrefix ?

This is correct. You will need to specify the version number in `BlobPrefix`. From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy?view=azure-devops#arguments):

[image]

Comment: Yes , but how each new commit or build will generate new name ? Raise +1

Comment: Can you please send me the syntax what should I write ?